# Get the location of a point in a box without shipout

Tags: shipout, pdfsavepos

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{hello \fbox{other [.] text} world.}
\box0
\end{document}
```

I can use zref-savepos to determine the location of the dot inside the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\zsavepos{leftmostpoint}hello \fbox{other [.\zsavepos{dotpoint}] text} world.}
\box0
\the\dimexpr\zposx{dotpoint}sp-\zposx{leftmostpoint}sp\relax
\end{document}
```

But:

- It requires the box to be shipped out
- It needs another compilation pass

Question: **is there a way to compute the location of the dot in the box, without shipout?**

I know that there is `\wd`, `\ht` and `\dp` for boxes, but nothing more.

Motivation: I want to be able to implement something similar to tikzmark for Asymptote ([How can I make arrow from parts of a formula in Asymptote? (or: measure the width of a label, get anchor around a label)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707398/how-can-i-make-arrow-from-parts-of-a-formula-in-asymptote-or-measure-the-widt)). For that, Asymptote uses a bidirectional pipe to measure the width, height and depth of the boxes, but I also want custom anchor inside the box.

Comment: I cannot answer, but am interested in replies. Might make a difference if you use lualatex? Also might make a difference if the box does not contain anything that might flow to the next page.

Comment: Possible resource: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642642/how-to-get-length-from-glue. (`\predisplaysize` can be abused to interesting effect, but if the boxes are nested then it's not useful.)